# Configuring velocity within a tomcat web application. (Cookbook wanted)

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, velocity

I have recently been introduced to the Velocity project.

I have written a template and have run it as a simple Java application.

Integration within my existing web project has not been that easy.

Can anyone supply a cookbook for integrating Velocity and Tomcat?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat is a servlet container; you don't need to integrate Velocity with it but rather with your application. How exactly that should be done depends on your application:

- If you're using Spring, it has VelocityViewResolver available along with [instructions on how to set it up](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html#view-velocity).
- If you're using straight servlets / JSP take a look at [VelocityViewServlet](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view/)
- Other frameworks (Struts / etc...) may or may not have built-in Velocity integration; take a look at [this page (bottom section)](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/PoweredByVelocity) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward way is to define a VelocityViewServlet in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>view</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.velocity.properties</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/velocity.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>view</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In velocity.properties

```
#resource loaders
resource.loader = production

production.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader
```

Then put your template at the root of your webapp and access it from the web browser using its name as the URL. e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/index.vm
```